# MS Call record subscription

Tags: call, microsoft-teams, subscription, microsoft-graph-api

I am setting up webhooks for Teams call records mentioned in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/callrecords-callrecord-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http .

My doubt is related to statement "Subscribe to change notifications to the /communications/callRecords endpoint.".

Can we use same notification url for multiple accounts with different tenant id ?
or Can we use same notification url for completely different organizations ?

Comment: If your app is configured for multi-tenant, I think it should work.

Comment: In case of different organizations  , they will have their separate apps. Now if i provide callRecord.read.all permission to those apps and call start subscription api but provide same notification url as mentioned in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/subscription-post-subscriptions?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http in request body for these 2 different organizations , will  it work ?

Comment: Sorry my bad, I think there is no use of using same subscription URL for different organizations apps because for all apps you will get notification at a single configured endpoint, which is not the ideal way.

Comment: so u mean it will work. actually my scenario needs single endpoint for different organizations. We can later differentiate based on tenantid and subscription id coming in notification along with call id .

Comment: @ChetanSharma-msft do you know if same url for different organization will work or not ?  I have only 1 tenant but changes that i am doing should support multiple, so cant test in local.

Comment: You can have one endpoint for single application and organization. It will work for multiple tenants if the application is configured as multitenant.

Comment: My scenario is multiple organizations, will same url work for different oragnizations ? 
In notification , we get tenant id, so we can differentiate organizations based on that . I want to know the reason in case this scenario will not work.

Comment: You will have only one messaging endpoint configured for the application. But if you use same endpoint for multiple organizations so all traffic will come to a single endpoint and it may break.

Comment: Thanks @Meghana-MSFT . i just want to confirm if we follow requirements mentioned in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/webhooks under Heading "Processing the change notification" then if traffic handled at my application handled properly, it will work . There is no issue from Microsoft side then ? It does not care whether multiple organization are using same url or different ?

Comment: We are checking this with the engineering team, We will update you.

Comment: We got an update from the engineering team saying, There is no technical constraint preventing us from using the same webhook endpoint. The webhook just needs to read the tenantId field to route notifications appropriately.
Note that each tenant does need its own subscription, but they can all have the same notificationUrl.

Comment: Thanks @Meghana-MSFT for clarifying my doubt. Have a good day :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no technical constraint preventing us from using the same webhook endpoint.

The webhook just needs to read the tenantId field to route notifications appropriately. Note that each tenant does need its own subscription, but they can all have the same notificationUrl.